# OrderBy with value from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I would like to order a Listview based on the products'name it displays. My website is made of several languages and thus I built a linked table with a product name for each languages.

When I try to sort it I always get this error

> DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
>   Parameter name: key

My code is the following:

```
IQueryable<Product> query = from p in _dbCtx.Products
                            where p.LanguageProduct.Any(lg => lg.Language == _currentCulture)
                            select p;
```

...

```
if (keys.Contains("OrderBy"))
{
    if (Request.QueryString["OrderBy"] == "NameAsc")
    query = query.OrderBy(t => t.LanguageProduct.Select(v => v.ProductName));  
}
```

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Maybe I haven't been clear enough. Therefore, I'll add some more code:

```
IQueryable<Product> query = from p in _dbCtx.Products
                                    where p.IsVisible == true
                                    where p.LanguageProduct.Any(lg => lg.Language == _currentCulture)
                                    select p;
        if (keys.Contains("Indiv"))
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Indiv"] == "IndivYes")
                query = query.Where(c => c.IsCustomizable == true);
            if (Request.QueryString["Indiv"] == "IndivNo")
                query = query.Where(c => c.IsCustomizable == false);
        }
        if (keys.Contains("OrderBy"))
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["OrderBy"] == "NameAsc")
                query = query.OrderBy(t => t.LanguageProduct.Select(v => v.ProductName));
            else if (Request.QueryString["OrderBy"] == "NameDes")
                query = query.OrderByDescending(t => t.LanguageProduct.Select(v => v.ProductName));
            else if (Request.QueryString["OrderBy"] == "PriceAsc")
                query = query.OrderBy(t => t.ListPrice);
            else if (Request.QueryString["OrderBy"] == "PriceDes")
                query = query.OrderByDescending(t => t.ListPrice);
        }
```

Everything works fine by adding successive where clauses to my query until it has to order by name. Hereunder is the structure of my database:

```
table:      Product                         ProductTranslation

columns:    id     ReferenceName            FKId   Language     ProductName  
Example:    1      FirstProduct             1       fr-FR       Produit 1
                                            1       de-DE       Produkt 1
                                            1       en-US       Product 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using this:

```
var queryable = query.SelectMany(p => p.LanguageProduct, (p, l) => new{p,l})
        .OrderBy(t => t.l.ProductName)
        .Select(t => t.p);
```

Comment: I have several filters in my code (represented by the ...) before ordering the IQueryable and which consist in adding where clauses to the query.
I don't think your solution might work in this case.

Comment: @user3713398 Changed my answer, look now